# Pass view to another view in Slim

Tags: php, slim

Im trying to send a view to another view and then render all. but i cant

```
$app->get('/',function () use ($app) {
    $data = array(
        'content' => $app->view->fetch('home.php')
    );
    $app->render('layout.php', $data);
});
```

how can i do this using Slim Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in latest version (2.4.0) of Slim framework:

```
$app->get('/',function () use ($app) {

  $content = $app->view->fetch('home.php');
  $app->render('layout.php', array('content' => $content)); 
});
```

In layout.php

```
<html>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</html>
```

Check here https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases under "View Template Data"